# Appscript does not execute after authorization under V8 compared to Rhino runtime

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a basic AppScript that creates a menu item, execute a function once the user clicks on the menu item. The function prompts the user to enter a url. This code is embedded in a read-only Google Doc, so users first need to make a copy of the Google Doc.

This was working as intended until I opted into the V8 runtime. Now, when a user clicks on the menu item "Create Quranic Report Cards," the standard authorization dialog boxes are presented to the user, and after clicking allow, the script does not present the dialog box, "Enter full link of your spreadsheet."

When I revert the runtime to legacy appscript (aka Rhino) the dialog box is presented as expected. I could not identify anything in the migration documentation (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration) that I need to implement to handle this.

Code snippet below. Help would be appreciated!

```
function onOpen() {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Report Cards')
    .addItem('Create Report Cards', 'termReport')
    .addToUi();
}

// Create Term Report
function termReport() {

  // Prompt user to provide google sheet URL
  ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  prompt = ui.prompt("Enter full link of your spreadsheet:", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Check if valid url was entered
  try {
    wsID = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(prompt.getResponseText()).getId();
  } catch(err) {
    ui.alert("You entered an invalid link for the spreadsheet. Please re-run script with correct link.");
    return;
  }
  ...
  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the `onOpen()` creates the menu item, the user has to complete the OAuth flow to use the function in the script. The OAuth dialog box will appear when the user clicks on a custom menu item which script requires special permissions.

Once the user completes the OAuth flow successfully, he can use the custom menu item function normally. As stated in the documentation this is the expected behavior: [Custom Menus G Suite](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) -> *"9. Now that the script is authorized, click the link you added to the page **again**. The function will now execute..."*